# Mapping and querying the web api in service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making a web api and have created several classes, the class controller and the service as well as the dto and the model.
In the controller I have the methods for post and get and the business logic is in the service

My question is how can I make the queries from the model class and map the queries to the dto

Service Layer:

```
  public class GermanyService : IGermanyService
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<GermanyDto>> All()
    {
         
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task Create(GermanyDto germany)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public class GermanyController
{
    private readonly IGermanyService _germanyService;

    public GermanyController(IGermanyService service)
    {
        _germanyService = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<GermanyDto>> Get(int id)
    {
        return await _germanyService.All();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post([FromBody]GermanyDto dto)
    {
        await _germanyService.Create(dto);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay :)

Use an interface implementation ->

seggregate your business logic's interfaces, so you have many of them, split into their single responsibilities and then join them in one:

Example

```
public interface IStreetName {
     string StreetName{get;set;}
}


public interface IPostCode {
    string PostCode {get;set;} 
}
```

... other implementations for an Address DTO f.x.

then

```
public interface IAddress : IPostCode, IStreetName, ...
{
    //should be empty
}
```

now you can Implement Iaddress on your DAL object, and not need an actual DTO -> because you ONLY reference the interface in your business logic.

etc.
Obviously, you would have to rename the intefaces for the properties on your "GermanyDTO", which I don't know what looks like.

EDIT:
Using mappers like "auto-mappers" or the like is usually a sign of 2 things.

1: You don't understand how to write effective mapping yourself.
2: Using a framework to accomplish something, doesn't absolve you from testing. And frameworks are notoriously difficult to test.
(Because, following proper procedure, you would have to test the interface between your code and the framework, and by extension the code between framework and 3rd part component, failing to do so, will setup you up for risks, between what you THINK the framwork does, and what it ACTUALLY does)

So Yes, using something like "Automapper" is at best a supression of a symptom rather than a cure.

Because the root cause is failing to understand how interfaces solve mappings.
And using a tool, to do something you can do cleaner yourself, and improve the structure of your entire system as a result? Is a no-brainer.

Just notice your own statement:
"Do you think it is effective? Automapper solves some of my issues"
You are seriously going to implement a direct dependency in your system, because of a framework?
You are admitting to writing bad code, because a framework can take away ... what? A little bit of boiler plate?

Comment: Thanks, do you think this is a very effective solution, because with automapper practically everything is done by itself. automapper takes the data from the backend and sends it to the frontend

Comment: This is effective, because: 
1. you aren't reliant on a framework, if the framework changes = code changes.

 
2. using the Seam pattern and composition pattern, to separate responsibilities/dependencies
will enable you to test code much more easily. 

The fact that you have an object called "GermanyDto" likely means there will be other types, like a "FranceDto" or some-such case, and in that case, would you prefer to write test cases for each instance that exists? Or just once for the interface?

Also now you can Extend without modification.

Comment: I will help you if you want, show me the DTO, and I will write you code for the All and Create methods you have listed.
by show me: Include the DTO class in your question.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to learn that myself, too. I just want to create dummy data first and send the data to the frontend. In the end I want it to appear with swagger it.